# Connecting via SSH from a PHP script

Tags: php, ssh

I am getting this error when trying to connect to a server via SSH from a PHP script. "Fatal error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()".

I checked my PHPINFO() and it shows libSSH Version = libssh2/1.4.2 but when I look in \php\ext I do not see php_ssh2.dll.  Also, I don't have show anything in my php.ini file about ssh.

I am very new to SSH and would love some advice on how to get this working.  I currently using XAMPP on a window machine for testing and I have a home server that I am trying to connect via SSH to.  I know that SSH is working and configured on the server because I am able to connect just fine using Putty.exe.  Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: While PHP may have SSH support compiled in, you might need to install [the PECL extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2) separately.

Comment: I took a look at this but I don't know how to install that extension.  The PECL comes with 2 .dll and a .pdb file.  I moved the .dll to etx folder and restarted apache but it won't start now.  I even tried to register the .dll using Regsvr32 and it gives me an error.  I wan not able to find documentation on how to install the extensions for windows.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP ssh2 extension [is not built for Windows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php).

You can try compiling it yourself, but that's probably a lot more work than you really want to put into this. Probably best to just use a Linux system for developing your project, where installing and using this extension is fairly trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the informaion. Is there another way to connect to the server via SSH without using the extensions?  I have read that it might be possible to do this using Exec() but I can't really find much information about the use or syntax.  Thanks

Comment: Sure, just install PHP on Linux...or maybe Cygwin. Any way you look at it, Linux is probably the path of least resistance here.

Comment: I have a shared hosting account with linux on it and I can do some testing from there as well.  It has just been easier until now to do it on my local machine.  However, my problem looks like I don't have the ability to install extensions on the shared hosting account.  That's why I was hoping to find another way to connect to my home server via ssh and run a few commands.  Still hoping I can make exec() work, but documentation about using it with ssh is proving difficult to find.

Comment: I ended up using PHPseclib to get around my issues. Thanks again for the help.